# I have a problem when I want to start the Wildfly server inside Netbeans 12, currently I work on a MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: java, macos

```
Deploying on WildFly Application Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: true
    force redeploy: true
Starting WildFly Application Server
WildFly Application Server Start Failed. Check whether the /Users/macos/development/freelancer/ban/jboss-eap-7.2-seg/bin/standalone.sh script is executable.
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `/Users/macos/development/freelancer/ban/jboss-eap-7.2-seg/bin/standalone.sh` is executable as the error suggests? (e.g., by running (test -x /Users/macos/development/freelancer/ban/jboss-eap-7.2-seg/bin/standalone.sh && echo "Executable" in the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if `standalone.sh` is executable, make it executable and try running it:

```
cd /Users/macos/development/freelancer/ban/jboss-eap-7.2-seg/bin
chmod +x ./standalone.sh
./standalone.sh
```

When this works, it then also should work in NetBeans IDE.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when executing the command I get the following error izsh: operation not permitted: ./standalone.sh